# Is there a simple linux command that will tell me what my display manager is?

Tags: command-line, display-manager

Is there a simple linux command that will tell me what my display manager is?

I'm using Xfce.  Are different desktop environments usually affiliated with different display managers?

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty good article on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/584373/how-to-check-using-the-command-line-which-display-manager-is-running

Answer (score 109):

Unfortunately the configuration differs for each distribution:

#### Debian/Ubuntu

```
/etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

#### RedHat & Fedora

```
/etc/sysconfig/desktop
```

see [Fedora docs: Switching desktop environments](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/switching-desktop-environments/#_manually_editing_the_system_configuration)

#### OpenSuSe

```
/etc/sysconfig/displaymanager
```

Comment: Huh, why are you telling me about configuration...?

Comment: @ptrcao Because it specifies what display manager you are using.

Comment: Suppose I don't know what my display manager is and I want to find out by using terminal.  How would I do that?

Comment: @ptrcao You would look into those files. Either opening them in your favorite editor, or just doing `cat`.

Comment: It has only one line in it: `/usr/bin/xdm` - does that mean xdm is my display manager?

Comment: @ptrcao Although I find that unlikely, it would seems so. There might be some other configuration file hidden elsewhere. What distribution are you using?

Comment: Why do you find that unlikely?  Btw, I'm using Debian 6 testing, 32 bit, running Xfce as the desktop environment.

Comment: @ptrcao It's not unlike, since xfce uses the display manager that is already installed. If for some reason you or another package installed xdm at some point, it makes sense to be the default and this is what you are using.

Comment: Ah ok, I guess it must've been default on Debian's install.

Comment: The mentioned file for OpenSUSE does contain settings for Display Manager, however it does not leave a trace about which one is used. Unless I overlooked something.

Answer (score 76):

If you are using a **systemd** based distribution, this command will give the name of the display manger currently configured because you may have more than one display manager installed.

```
grep 'ExecStart=' /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service
```

Output will be something like

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mdm
```

Looks like I am using mint display manager.

Answer (score 61):

If you're using systemd, then

```
systemctl status display-manager
```

Will display the name and status of the active display manager service on your machine.

Comment: With Debian 9, this is the only one that worked for me. The other systemd methods returned nothing.

Answer (score 30):

There isn't. The display manager is not necessarily related to anything else that's running on the same X server. The display manager runs before you log in; it's chosen by the system administrator. Everything else (window manager, session manager, desktop environment, …) is chosen by the user. There doesn't even have to be a display manager: if you log in in text mode and start the GUI with [`startx`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinit), no display manager is involved.

You can check [which display manager is the default one on your system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/is-there-a-simple-linux-command-that-will-tell-me-what-my-display-manager-is/20376#20376). This will only give the right answer under some common but not universal assumptions. If you manually ran a different manager for whatever reason, this method won't tell you.

A good bet is to find out the process ID of the X server: its parent process is probably a display manager, if there is one. This requires that your clients are running on the same machine as the X server. `lsof /tmp/.X11-unix/X${DISPLAY#:}` will show the X server process (assuming the X sockets live in `/tmp/.X11-unix`).

```
x=$(lsof -F '' /tmp/.X11-unix/X0); x=${x#p}
ps -p $(ps -o ppid -p $x)
```

(Explanation: `lsof -F ''` prints output like `p1234`. The `-F` option means a machine-parseable output format, and `''` means to only print the PID, with the letter `p` before it. `x=${x#p}` strips off the initial letter `p`. The last line obtains the PID of the parent of the X server (`ps -o ppid -p $x`), and calls `ps` to show information about that parent process.)

Some distributions allow installing multiple display managers. There'll only be a single one running unless you have a multiseat system though. To list all installed display manager packages under Debian and derivatives:

```
aptitude -F %p search '~i ~P^x-display-manager$'
```

or

```
</var/lib/dpkg/status awk '
    /^Package: / {package = $2}
    /^Provides: .*x-display-manager/ {print package}'
```

Answer (score 12):

The display manager name should be in DESKTOP_SESSION

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```

returns "gnome" for me.

**EDIT**
You're right.  They're going back and forth on that on XFCEs [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6376) so it probably isn't very reliable.

Comment: @frabjous: What about gdm and kdm? Are they display managers too or just login managers?

Comment: I must've accidentally deleted frabjous' comment just above because I remember he remarked that Gnome is a desktop environment, not a display manager.  This thread is abound with confusion...

Comment: This gives information about… the desktop session, which is likely to be the same thing as your desktop environment, but may be something else altogether if you're not using a desktop environment or you have a peculiar configuration. On the machine where I'm writing this, `$DESKTOP_SESSION` is `unknown`.

Comment: +1, echo $DESKTOP_SESSION also returns gnome to me... but maybe this only works for gnome?

Comment: If it only works for gnome, this command  will only help you deduce "yes you have Gnome or no you don't have gnome". When the question wants to find out more than that.

Comment: Yes, the more I looked into that the more it seems to be a "we'll set that if we get around to it" feature.  Gnome honors it, KDE sort of does (with "default" or "kde" or "kde4"), and XFCE might.  Yeesh.

Comment: returns cinnamon for me, so this is clearly not displaying the dm but the de.

Comment: This answer confuses the difference between a display manager and a desktop session (which is launched by a display manager); `gnome` is not a display manager (`gdm` is the GNOME Display Manager). The `DESKTOP_SESSION` environment variable does *not* provide any information about the **display manager** – only the desktop session (which is likely to be the same as the *desktop environment*).

Comment: I use Sddm and Lubuntu 20_04 and the variable is not set.

Comment: Returns nothing for me on Crostini.

Answer (score 5):

Like @Gilles said, the display manager will start your desktop environment.

According to the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DisplayManager), mostly these end with `dm`, only exception is `slim`.

So this should suffice for most of people's needs:

```
ps auxf | awk '{print $11}' | \grep --color -e dm$ -e slim$
```

Or to be sure, it exists as a parent process, and is not forked (except from the init system):

```
ps auxf | awk '{print $11}' | \grep -e "^/.*dm$" -e "/.*slim$"
```

Comment: This is the only solution here that worked for me. Figured out that my Fedora 23 minimal with LXDE add-on (not the LXDE Spin) is running `lightdm`. The RedHat/Fedora solution from the top answer didn't work, the configuration seems to have moved.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this command

systemctl |grep "Display Manager"

This will provide below output.

[anil@localhost Desktop]$ systemctl |grep "Display Manager"
xdm.service                                                                              loaded active running   X11 Display Manager

Now you can see xdm.service listed just above loaded active running and that is your Display Manager

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via a third-party script called *screenfetch*

Screenfetch is a bash script available for Linux that displays system information alongside the ASCII version of the Linux distribution Logo of the system

Install via package manager
`sudo apt-get install screenfetch` (assuming you're on Debian variants)

and just run 

 `screenfetch`

In your terminal

Project link
https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch

Comment: This works on Crostini. Crostini apparently uses Sommelier.

Answer (score 2):

After you enable the `display-manager.service`, a symlinked file to the specified or default display manager in use -- as you might have multiple one on the same desktop environment -- should be at `/etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service`

```
file /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service
```

This method reliably worked out for me on ubuntu-20 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Another systemd approach.

This one uses the `show` command to filter out a property of the `display-manager` service:

```
➜ systemctl --property=Id,Description show display-manager.service
Id=sddm.service
Description=Simple Desktop Display Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, there is a lot of confusion in this thread. The original question is what display manager, not desktop manager or window manager. 
I'm currently running Xfwm4 which is Xfce window manager, and lxdm which is lightweight X11 display manager (from LXDE, not Xfce). You should be able to see what display manager you are using via htop. You've probably long since discovered the answer over the past 4 years :)

Comment: Actually never did...  In fact gave up on Linux altogether and went over to the dark side :D

Answer (score -1):

In some case, wmctrl could help. This utility is compatible with a lot of windows managers.

```
wmcrt -m
```

should display the name of the currently used window manager.

Comment: A [window manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/window_manager) is not the same thing as a [display manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager).