# Delete all secondary software in a Debian-influenced system

Tags: ubuntu

In Ubuntu 18.04 I want to delete all secondary software (all software which isn't drivers or that is required for basic operating of the system).

For example in Ubuntu I want to delete all games, all general usage apps (as for Email), all Amazon apps, the GUI automatic updater, and even the software center manager, etc.

I want to have a super minimal Ubuntu that I would gear up from scratch, per my needs via a script I already prepared.

How could I remove all that software in one go, fast? Thanks.

EDIT --- I need GUI because I love the Ubuntu red-purple-orange-brown GUI.

Comment: A similar question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426064/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with [Ubuntu Server](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/), which is a very minimal install if you do not select any of the additional packages.

Comment: But I need Ubuntu GUI. It has GUI?

Comment: You can install a Graphical User Interface as needed

Comment: You install it from the CLI so you get the same Ubuntu server, bare Ubuntu, but with a GUI?

Comment: No, you will download the correct iso file for your needs at [this link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/), install it like you would regular desktop Ubuntu, then run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` when you log in to get the Ubuntu Graphical environment. This is pretty much as minimal as you can get for a graphical Ubuntu install.