# Automatic login still doesn't work after editing custom.conf

Tags: rhel, gnome, login, autologin

I've edited /etc/gdm/custom.conf to show the following:

```
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=username
```

Where username is obviously the username I'd like to automatically log into.

I don't know if it matters or not, but I do have multiple users. In mind this should not matter, however, since we're specifying a username here in the settings.

I'm using RHEL6.4. Any ideas?

Comment: I do not have a RHEL6 install handy but I'd give these methods a try as well. http://crazyedy.com/tech/?p=52

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that guide. I don't have /usr/share/gdm/defaults.conf, but I'm not sure I am suppose to in light of having /etc/gdm/custom.conf. Should I?

Comment: I would try what's discussed in that post, but do it a piece at a time, and if something wasn't there and it didn't work, back it out afterwards.

Comment: Again, I have. It's not that difficult of a guide to follow. Open up /etc/gdm/custom.conf and change those values. I get it. I did so, and no dice. It doesn't make sense to me either. It really should be that simple to do. I don't mean to sound rude, I'm just growing frustrated. When it comes to solving this everything I've found has been like listening to a broken record playing the same thing over and over again.

Comment: OK, sorry didn't mean to offend, just looking to eliminate everything we can from the list of possible leads. When I've done this in the past it really has been that simple, so you might have found a bug. Do you have a paid subscription for RHEL?

Comment: No, no, you're fine. I do. I guess I could go through those channels. Seems kind of silly, but I might have to.

Comment: I'll keep looking, but there might be a diff. b/w RHEL and CentOS/Fedora in this one respect. Also we can open issues on multiple trackers, CentOS & RHEL. Keep this up to date if you make any progress.

Comment: I just installed a virtual machine with RHEL 6.4 on it with no added packages. Just as it is, right out of the box. The stupid auto login thing works just fine there! Currently trying to track down what it is that I installed or configured that might be stopping things from working correctly.

On a side note, I might try changing the exec line in /etc/init/tty.conf to "exec /sbin/mingetty –autologin username password $TTY" http://lifeforce4.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/centos-6-single-user-auto-login/

Comment: So that's good progress then. At least you know the issue lies with your system. I'm dump a list of RPMs from both and do a sdiff of the 2 lists. Also do the same b/w `/etc` dirs. the difference likely lies within 1 of those 2 areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this but I would suggest first to make sure `gdm` is actually your current display manager and that you're using the correct file: check the output of `cat /etc/sysconfig/desktop` and take a look if there are other `.conf` files in `/etc/gdm/`. Maybe trying renaming the file to `gdm.conf`.

Also, did you try GUI solutions or do you require something that can be done from command line? You should be able to configure `gdm` with `sudo gdmsetup`.

Comment: There you have comment rights now. Leave this though, it's actually enough of a answer fragment. See if you can flesh it out further.

Comment: I don't have /etc/sysconfig/desktop and the only conf file I have in /etc/gdm is custom.conf. You mentioned renaming the custom.conf file to gdm.conf. What would be searching for a conf file of that name? I see scripts looking for custom.conf, but not a gdm.conf. Also, gdmsetup doesn't work.

Comment: @Stradigos Sorry, that was just a wild guess, since `mdm` uses `mdm.conf`. After some research it seems that `gdmsetup` was deprecated which seems weird to me. [This link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20376/54265) said `/etc/sysconfig/desktop` should exist in Red Hat but I can't test that on my distro. At this point I don't really don't know about anything that could help you, other than try if something happens after running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` (which you probably did at some point already).

Comment: @slm Oh well, thanks. That's generous of you. I'll use this privilege wisely.

Comment: There's some relevant info on this page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Configuration. Some of it's ArchLinux specific but the rest is related to RHEL.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but when I echo $DISPLAY_MANAGER it tells me gnome. GDM and Gnome... they are talking about the same thing, but are they really? At least with RHEL 6.4, X and GDM seem so disconnected with each other now. I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, I was able to finally get it working. There was a related file that got overwritten with garbage somehow. No idea how, but I just needed to restore it.

Comment: +1 `sudo gdmsetup` worked for me. There is an option specifically for auto login where you can enter the username. :)