# What causes the login screen to be scrambled after firmware install on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, graphics, gdm3

After installing Debian 9.0.1 (gnome flavor) on an older PC and then installing firmware with:

```
apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

, the login screen looks scrambled:
[image: initial login screen]
The mouse cursor looks normal and works as expected, and if I click on the colors corresponding to the username field the password field becomes active:

[image: password field active]

and I can log in. After that everything looks normal.

I will add more info, hoping it is useful:

```
$ sudo lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV515 [Radeon X1300/X1550]

$ sudo dmesg | grep -E 'drm|radeon' | grep -iE 'firmware|microcode'[    8.437059] [drm] Loading R500 Microcode
[    8.550995] radeon 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/R520_cp.bin

$ sudo xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x54 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:ATI Radeon X1300/X1550 @ pci:0000:02:00.0


$ sudo DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV515

$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org R300 Project
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV515
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

ps -e | grep X
626 tty1     00:00:00 Xwayland
729 tty2     00:02:33 Xorg

pstree
systemd─┬─ModemManager─┬─{gdbus}
    │              └─{gmain}
    ├─NetworkManager─┬─dhclient
    │                ├─{gdbus}
    │                └─{gmain}
    ├─accounts-daemon─┬─{gdbus}
    │                 └─{gmain}
    ├─anacron
    ├─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
    ├─colord─┬─{gdbus}
    │        └─{gmain}
    ├─cron
    ├─dbus-daemon
    ├─firefox-esr─┬─{BgHangManager}
    │             ├─{Cache I/O}
    │             ├─{Cache2 I/O}
    │             ├─{Cert Verify}
    │             ├─{Closing Service}
    │             ├─{Compositor}
    │             ├─{DNS Resolver #1}
    │             ├─{DNS Resolver #2}
    │             ├─{DNS Resolver #3}
    │             ├─{DNS Resolver #4}
    │             ├─2*[{DOM Worker}]
    │             ├─{GMPThread}
    │             ├─{Gecko_IOThread}
    │             ├─{HTML5 Parser}
    │             ├─{Hang Monitor}
    │             ├─{IPDL Background}
    │             ├─{ImageBridgeChil}
    │             ├─{ImageIO}
    │             ├─{ImgDecoder #1}
    │             ├─{ImgDecoder #2}
    │             ├─6*[{JS Helper}]
    │             ├─{JS Watchdog}
    │             ├─{Link Monitor}
    │             ├─{Proxy R~olution}
    │             ├─{Socket Thread}
    │             ├─{SoftwareVsyncTh}
    │             ├─{Timer}
    │             ├─{URL Classifier}
    │             ├─{dconf worker}
    │             ├─2*[{firefox-esr}]
    │             ├─{gdbus}
    │             ├─{gmain}
    │             ├─{localStorage DB}
    │             ├─{mozStorage #1}
    │             ├─{mozStorage #2}
    │             ├─{mozStorage #3}
    │             ├─{mozStorage #4}
    │             ├─{mozStorage #5}
    │             ├─{mozStorage #6}
    │             └─{threaded-ml}
    ├─gdm3─┬─gdm-session-wor─┬─gdm-wayland-ses─┬─gnome-session-b─┬─gnome-se+
    │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gnome-sh+
    │      │                 │                 │                 ├─{dconf w+
    │      │                 │                 │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │      │                 │                 │                 └─{gmain}
    │      │                 │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │      │                 │                 └─{gmain}
    │      │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │      │                 └─{gmain}
    │      ├─gdm-session-wor─┬─gdm-x-session─┬─Xorg─┬─{InputThread}
    │      │                 │               │      └─{radeon_cs:0}
    │      │                 │               ├─gnome-session-b─┬─evolution-+
    │      │                 │               │                 ├─gnome-sett+
    │      │                 │               │                 ├─gnome-shel+
    │      │                 │               │                 ├─gnome-soft+
    │      │                 │               │                 ├─ssh-agent
    │      │                 │               │                 ├─tracker-ex+
    │      │                 │               │                 ├─tracker-mi+
    │      │                 │               │                 ├─tracker-mi+
    │      │                 │               │                 ├─tracker-mi+
    │      │                 │               │                 ├─{dconf wor+
    │      │                 │               │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │      │                 │               │                 └─{gmain}
    │      │                 │               ├─{gdbus}
    │      │                 │               └─{gmain}
    │      │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │      │                 └─{gmain}
    │      ├─{gdbus}
    │      └─{gmain}
    ├─gnome-keyring-d─┬─{gdbus}
    │                 ├─{gmain}
    │                 └─{timer}
    ├─gsd-printer─┬─{gdbus}
    │             └─{gmain}
    ├─ibus-daemon─┬─ibus-dconf─┬─{dconf worker}
    │             │            ├─{gdbus}
    │             │            └─{gmain}
    │             ├─ibus-engine-sim─┬─{gdbus}
    │             │                 └─{gmain}
    │             ├─ibus-ui-gtk3─┬─{dconf worker}
    │             │              ├─{gdbus}
    │             │              ├─{gmain}
    │             │              └─{radeon_cs:0}
    │             ├─{gdbus}
    │             └─{gmain}
    ├─2*[ibus-x11─┬─{gdbus}]
    │             ├─{gmain}]
    │             └─{radeon_cs:0}]
    ├─minissdpd
    ├─mount.ntfs
    ├─packagekitd─┬─{gdbus}
    │             └─{gmain}
    ├─polkitd─┬─{gdbus}
    │         └─{gmain}
    ├─pulseaudio─┬─{alsa-sink-AD198}
    │            └─{alsa-source-AD1}
    ├─rsyslogd─┬─{in:imklog}
    │          ├─{in:imuxsock}
    │          └─{rs:main Q:Reg}
    ├─rtkit-daemon───2*[{rtkit-daemon}]
    ├─systemd─┬─(sd-pam)
    │         ├─at-spi-bus-laun─┬─dbus-daemon
    │         │                 ├─{dconf worker}
    │         │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─at-spi2-registr─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─dbus-daemon
    │         └─pulseaudio─┬─{alsa-sink-AD198}
    │                      └─{alsa-source-AD1}
    ├─systemd─┬─(sd-pam)
    │         ├─at-spi-bus-laun─┬─dbus-daemon
    │         │                 ├─{dconf worker}
    │         │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─at-spi2-registr─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─dbus-daemon
    │         ├─dconf-service─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │               └─{gmain}
    │         ├─evolution-addre─┬─evolution-addre─┬─{dconf worker}
    │         │                 │                 ├─{evolution-addre}
    │         │                 │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │         │                 │                 └─{gmain}
    │         │                 ├─{dconf worker}
    │         │                 ├─{evolution-addre}
    │         │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─evolution-calen─┬─evolution-calen─┬─{dconf worker}
    │         │                 │                 ├─2*[{evolution-calen}]
    │         │                 │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │         │                 │                 ├─{gmain}
    │         │                 │                 └─{pool}
    │         │                 ├─evolution-calen─┬─{dconf worker}
    │         │                 │                 ├─{evolution-calen}
    │         │                 │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │         │                 │                 └─{gmain}
    │         │                 ├─{dconf worker}
    │         │                 ├─{evolution-calen}
    │         │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─evolution-sourc─┬─{dconf worker}
    │         │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─gnome-shell-cal─┬─{dconf worker}
    │         │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │         │                 ├─{gmain}
    │         │                 └─2*[{gnome-shell-cal}]
    │         ├─gnome-terminal-─┬─bash───pstree
    │         │                 ├─{dconf worker}
    │         │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─goa-daemon─┬─{dconf worker}
    │         │            ├─{gdbus}
    │         │            ├─{gmain}
    │         │            └─{goa-daemon}
    │         ├─goa-identity-se─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │                 ├─{gmain}
    │         │                 └─{pool}
    │         ├─gvfs-afc-volume─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │                 ├─{gmain}
    │         │                 └─{gvfs-afc-volume}
    │         ├─gvfs-goa-volume─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─gvfs-gphoto2-vo─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─gvfs-mtp-volume─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─gvfs-udisks2-vo─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         ├─gvfsd─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │       └─{gmain}
    │         ├─gvfsd-fuse─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │            ├─{gmain}
    │         │            ├─{gvfs-fuse-sub}
    │         │            └─2*[{gvfsd-fuse}]
    │         ├─gvfsd-metadata─┬─{gdbus}
    │         │                └─{gmain}
    │         ├─mission-control─┬─{dconf worker}
    │         │                 ├─{gdbus}
    │         │                 └─{gmain}
    │         └─tracker-store─┬─{dconf worker}
    │                         ├─{gdbus}
    │                         ├─{gmain}
    │                         └─4*[{pool}]
    ├─systemd-journal
    ├─systemd-logind
    ├─systemd-timesyn───{sd-resolve}
    ├─systemd-udevd
    ├─udisksd─┬─{cleanup}
    │         ├─{gdbus}
    │         ├─{gmain}
    │         └─{probing-thread}
    ├─upowerd─┬─{gdbus}
    │         └─{gmain}
    └─wpa_supplicant
```

Before installing the Gnome version I've tried the Cinnamon flavor which didn't have this problem so I suspect it is somehow related to Gnome? Or better yet, gdm3?

(According to the first answer on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/is-there-a-simple-linux-command-that-will-tell-me-what-my-display-manager-is) question, I have gdm3:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/gdm3
```

)

I've just become aware of the fact that there is no problem with the login screen after screen lock after a period of inactivity.

Comment: Can you share a picture of the login screen?

Comment: `loginctl show-session 1 -p Type` gnome3 forces wayland.  and `pstree`

Comment: Thank you for for taking interest in my question, @Bahamut. `loginctl show-session 1 -p Type` gives me `Failed to get session path: No session '1' known` and I've edited the question to include the `pstree` result.

Comment: I see the Problem, but I don't know how to fix it and what it cause.  Gdm3 starts 2 gdm-sessions, one with wayland on tty1  and another with xorg on tty2.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks again for your time, I now at least have a clue where to start looking for answers.