# How to determine which window managers are installed from the command line?

Tags: debian, command-line, window-manager

How can I determine which window managers are installed from the command line? I use Ubuntu.

---

I know that:

- One can [determine which window manager is running with](https://askubuntu.com/q/72549/44876):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wmctrl
  wmctrl -m
  ```
- One can [view the default display manager on Debian/Ubuntu with](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20376/16704):

  ```
  /etc/X11/default-display-manager
  ```

Comment: Are you looking for some other commands to get the current display manager?

Comment: @GAD3R No, I am looking for a command that would list all installed window managers.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to find *all* window managers programmatically because any program could potentially act as a window manager and [it's impossible to write a program that knows what an arbitrary program does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). However, if you limit the search to *window managers provided by a Debian package*, there's an easy way. All window managers in Debian provide the `x-window-manager` [alternative](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives).

```
update-alternatives --list x-window-manager
```

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro “Gnome” isn't a window manager. Individual window managers provide the `x-window-manager` alternative, e.g. `metacity`, `mutter`, …

Answer (score 0):

This `psstree` command displays the window manager(s) presently use. And group the result(s) per application and their relationships with other item(s).

---

Below is the same answer as above. But with details if you're interested in those.

Three steps:

1. If not already done, execute this command to install the "pstree" package

   `sudo apt-get install pstree`
2. Using Terminal/Command line, execute this command

   `psstree`
3. Within the result, search for the keyword "gdm". On the right side of "gdm" is the presently use Window Manager. For example:

   > gdm-wayland-ses─┬─gnome-session

   Means GNOME Wayland

   > gdm-x-session─┬─Xorg

   Means GNOME X11

One of the main benefit of pstree is that if you have mutliple Window Manager use at once, then pstree will display which Window Manager is use per application. Plus the application relationship with other items.

pstree has many optional parameters. For example, execute this command to display only trees rooted at processes of this user

Format: `pstree <USERNAME>`

Example: `pstree jdoe`

Comment: The question shows how to determine which window manager is running, and the OP is clear that that is *not* what he is asking.