# Removing login username password screen to Autologin

Tags: password, user-input

I am using UP Board. IT has Ubilinux installed in it. I have made a browser kiosk so that it automatically logs in to the browser full screen mode but I am having an issue on reboot. Whenever I try to reboot  I have to enter a password on Login screen. I want it to be removed so that it can auto logged in without any input from user.[image: The boot up page]

[image: The OS selection screen. Maybe version would help you?]

[image: Login Page. This is the page I want to remove. I have several options as you can see on top left corner 8n Session. I want to use LXDE as my current session.]

Comment: can you tell us which display manager ubilinux uses? Autologin usually has to do with /etc/<name of display manager>.conf file

Comment: if it is gdm, take a look at https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-automatic.html.en

Comment: I think its LXDE. How do i know which display manager I am using?

Comment: [see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/is-there-a-simple-linux-command-that-will-tell-me-what-my-display-manager-is) since ubilinux is based on debian , do `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`. Most probably and by the looks of it your display manager is lxdm. For that autologin procedure is explained [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDM#Autologin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a file named sddm.conf in /etc/ directory. I placed this in it. Now I can login without any password.
[Autologin]
User=up
Session=LXDE

Answer (score 0):

Since your Display Manager seems to be `lxdm`, you should follow the following procedure. You have to edit the Display manager Config options for autologin.
The file is `/etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf`.

1. `sudo nano /etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf`
2. Find the line `#autologin=something`
3. Replace it with `autologin=UP` or whatever your username happens to be.
4. Reboot

For more info see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDM#Autologin)