# Choose lightdm login screen location in multi monitor setup

Tags: fedora, x11, nvidia, xfce, session

I am running Fedora XFCE with an NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti that is connected via 3 cables to 2 monitors.

Display port is connected twice to the same monitor (for PBP)
HDMI is connected to another monitor

Display Port 1 of my Monitor is the primary screen in XFCE, whereas Display Port 2 of my Monitor is disabled in my XFCE session. However, the login comes before I am a logged in user where the x settings are loaded, so somehow, it is always displayed on Display Port 2.

When I go into the Nvidia settings, I can see that the disabled monitor is DP-0 and the primary monitor is DP-4. However, like I said, in the monitor it's in DP-1 and DP-2, so where does DP-0 and DP-4 come from and why are they reversed? Is there a way to change this easily?

**Update**
What I tried so far

- In `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` added the lines (where dualmon.sh is `xrandr --output DP-4 --primary`

  - `display-setup-script=/usr/bin/dualmon.sh`
  - `session-setup-script=/usr/bin/dualmon.sh`
- In `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` set `active-monitor` under the `[greeter]` section to

  - 0
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - DP-4

None of this worked. The login screen is still displayed on DP-0 (DisplayPort 2) and not on DP-4 (DisplayPort 1)

Answer (score 1):

*A few words before:* This is probably not a complete solution (but I don't have enough reputation here to write a comment to ask for more input) and you will maybe have to work without GUI for configuration or even temporarily disable your GUI for Linux - so don't be afraid of shell commands (and get familiar with a text mode editor).

---

The login is driven by the "display manager", so to solve this, you first have to find out, which display manager you are using.
Popular choices would be

- xdm (very basic)
- gdm (Gnome)
- lxdm (LXDE display manager)
- kdm (KDE display manager)
- lightdm (from Canonical, the makers of Ubuntu Linux)

And there are also lots of others.

To find out, which one you are running, you can have a look into */etc/sysconfig/desktop* (RedHat/Fedora specific location!)
(according to [Is there a simple linux command that will tell me what my display manager is?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/is-there-a-simple-linux-command-that-will-tell-me-what-my-display-manager-is#20376))

Then you either update your question with the name of the display manager, or dig on by yourself.

On the commandline or in a script you can find out about and configure your monitors with the `xrandr` tool.

If you installed a standard Fedora installation and switched to XFCE later, there is a good chance that you will use gdm, and maybe also have GUI tools installed to configure it - at least, if you use the default desktop mode (Gnome?) temporarily to do the configuration.

Comment: I have lightdm (through direct Fedora XFCE install) and found these solutions https://askubuntu.com/questions/234930/choose-lightdm-login-screen-location-in-multi-monitor-setup, however, none of them worked. The one with `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` didn't change anything. I used this command: `xrandr --output DP-4 --primary` (DP-4 like I said from xrandr). And the other one in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` also didn't work. I tried multiple settings for `active-monitor`. I tried `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and even `DP-4` but none of them worked. My screen is still always black.